# Closing a bound form without saving changes

Tags: vba, ms-access

Quick question here, hoping for a concise sensible solution.

I have a bound form purely for data entry (cannot browse records, only insert them). 
I will have a lot of users that screw up. To avoid dirty data, I want them to confirm that the form is correct before submitting the record.

Problem is, as soon as I input ANYTHING on the form, access creates and saves a record.

I want the record to ONLY be saved and committed if the user clicks 'Submit'. If they click close or exit the application, I do not want that partially completed record in the database.

Without using an unbound form and calling an insert function, is there a simple solution?

Comment: You can undo a record as long as you do not have a subform.

Comment: @remou How does this effect the autonumber? Say I have two concurrent users on the form. User 1 Opens the form and begins to enter data first. User 2 then opens the form and enters data himself. User 1 decides he has better things to do than data entry and clicks the 'undo' button. I'm guessing this would result in a gap in numbers (like an insert then a delete, rather than a rollback or lack of commit?)

Comment: Check this out too [: you could have a boolean to be checked before form updated](http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/891249-how-stop-bound-forms-updating-automatically). In terms of keep the consistency of autoincrementer, you could always have a validation before an insert takes place...

Comment: @bonCodigo An autonumber should never be used as a sequential number.

Comment: @Remou +1 really nice point. [why?](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/values-autonumber-field-not-sequential-why-t3991443.html). Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An autonumber is there to be unique, not sequential. If you need a sequential number, do not use autonumber. Autonumber should never be shown to the user. It can never be relied upon to be anything but unique, and if you mess about enough, not even that.

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
If Me.AText = "Invalid" Then
    Me.Undo
    Cancel = True
End If
End Sub
```

Note that a form with a subform may not work with undo, because the record is committed on change from the subform to the main form and vice versa and it all gets quite complicated.

Comment: Yeah, I have a subform with a many-one relationship to the parent form.If someone was to cancel/undo, I doubt they would have gotten to the point of filling out the subform, so this may be enough.If not, I could just execute a delete query on the related table before undoing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Remou's method is definitely the quickest, here is another based on my comment ;)

```
Option Explicit

Private blnGood As Boolean

Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click()
    blnGood = True
    Call DoCmd.RunCommand(acCmdSaveRecord)
    blnGood = False
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not blnGood Then
        Cancel = True
        Call MsgBox(Prompt:="click submit to save the record", Title:="Before Update")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to create a clear button in case the user made an errors and wants to clear the entire form and start over.

```
Private Sub btnClear_Click() 
  If Me.Dirty = True Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
    Exit Sub
  End If
End Sub`
```

I sometimes find the before_update event to act weird so I generally disable the close (x) button in properties and add a close button of my own that prompts the user if he wants to abandon the data on screen.

```vb
Private Sub close_Click()
 Dim Answer As Integer
 If Me.Dirty = True Then
    Dim Response As Integer
    ' Displays a message box with the yes and no options.
    Response = MsgBox(Prompt:="Do you wish to discard data?", Buttons:=vbYesNo)
    ' If statement to check if the yes button was selected.
    If Response = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
        DoCmd.Close
        Else
        Me.Clear.SetFocus
    End If
 Else
    ' The no button was selected.
    DoCmd.Close
  End If
End Sub
```